# Is there a standard way to convert from container<Type1> to container<Type2>?

Tags: c++, list, containers

I have two classes `A` and `B`, and an implicit conversion operator exists to go from one to the other, so that:

```
A a;
B b;
b = a; // Works
```

Is there a standard way to convert a `std::list<A>` to a `std::list<B>` ? (Or even from `std::vector<A>` to a `std::list<B>`).

I know I can iterate trough to the list and build the second list item by item, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution.

Unfortunately **I cannot use `boost`** but out of curiosity as a bonus question, if boost can handle this, I'd be happy to know how too.

Comment: I guess this must have been asked before, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, yes. Each sequence container type has a template constructor that takes a pair of iterators (an iterator range) as an input. It can be used to construct one sequence from another, regardless of the sequence types, as long as the sequence element types are convertible to each other. Like for example

```
std::vector<A> v;
...
std::list<B> l(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Also sequence containers have `assign` member function which does the same thing with assignment semantics (as opposed to initialization semantics).

```
std::vector<A> v;
std::list<B> l;
...
l.assign(v.begin(), v.end()); // replaces the contents of `l`
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. And I can't believe I didn't thought of it. Many thanks ;)

Comment: if A type is not convertible to B type, what should be the behavior ?

Comment: depending on eaxtly what you are doing, and who owns the list, std::copy may be worth a look as well, possibly with an inserter iterator

Comment: @bjskishore123: It will simply fail to compile. Where, how and with what diagnostic message - depends on the implementation.

Comment: +1: Simplicity is elegance. Note that the range of iterators can be used also with `insert` (about the only thing note mentioned here).